# Does a python string include the quotation marks?

Tags: python-3.x

For ('bobby'), is the string here 'bobby' or just bobby? I've tried to research into it but the other questions people ask are more complicated. I only want to know whether a full python string includes or doesn't include the '' marks.

Comment: `len('bobby') == 5` should give you a hint.  Quotes are just for definition and display purposes.  To define the string with quotes would look like `"'bobby'"` (length 7)

Comment: No, it doesn't... You can just print to verify

Answer (score 1):

If you are declaring a string, you need the quotation marks, like this example:

```
a = "Hello"
```

However, if you are just talking about the string itself, the quotations are not part of it. If I were to print variable a that I declared above, the output would be Hello, not "Hello".

```
print(a) -> Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

A string is enclosed within the quotation mark, it does not mean that quotations are included in the string. The quotations are given just to tell the compiler that it is a string data type.

```
Ex -> "Hello"
      'Hello'
```

But if you include double or single quotes inside single or double quotes in python respectively, then the inner quotation will be treated as a string.

```
Ex -> 'Ram said, "I love apples."'
      "Ram said, 'I love apples.'"
```